# ¿Cómo implemento de forma correcta UCrop y que la imagen recortada se suba a firebase? La app se cierra al intentar recortar una imagen

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase

estoy intentando implementar un crop image con Yalantis/Ucrop en Android Studio y java, en el editor el código no presenta un ningún error pero al seleccionar la imagen en la app debería iniciar la actividad crop pero se queda en negro. No sé que estoy haciendo mal, recién estoy aprendiendo así que es agradecería mucho su ayuda para encontrar una solución.
Lo que intento hacer es que el usuario al dar clic para agregar una foto de perfil, se muestre la galeria y seleccionar una imagen (lo normal), luego permitir recortar la imagen y que esta se almacene en firebase. Antes de añadir el crop, funcionaba normal, el usuario elegía la imagen y esta se almacenaba en firebase pero con el crop como ya mencioné antes cuando debería recortarse laimagen se queda la pantalla en negro.

Esta es la dependencia que agregué al build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.github.krokyze:ucropnedit:2.2.8'
```

Código del Fragmento PerfilFragment en donde intento implementar el crop:

```
public class PerfilFragment extends Fragment {

RecyclerView datosActuales_rec;

FirebaseDatabase db;
DatabaseReference usersRef;
FirebaseAuth auth;
FirebaseUser user;
FirebaseStorage storage;

List<UserModel> userModelList;
DatosActualesAdapter datosActualesAdapter;
ShapeableImageView profileIMG, addfotoperfil;

EditText nombreAp, direccion, telef;
Button actualizar;

private int previousHeightDiffrence = 0;
private final int KEYBOARD_HEIGHT_THRESHOLD = 150;
private View rootView;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_perfil, container, false);

    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    user = auth.getCurrentUser();
    usersRef = db.getReference("Users").child(auth.getUid());
    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();


    datosActuales_rec = root.findViewById(R.id.datosActuales_rec);
    datosActuales_rec.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false));

    userModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    datosActualesAdapter = new DatosActualesAdapter(getActivity(), userModelList);
    datosActuales_rec.setAdapter(datosActualesAdapter);

    usersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot datasnapshot) {
            userModelList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot :
                    datasnapshot.getChildren()) {
                UserModel user = datasnapshot.getValue(UserModel.class);
                userModelList.add(user);
                String nombre = user.getNombreAp();
                String direccion = user.getDireccion();
                String correo = user.getEmail();
                String telefono = user.getTelefono();


                String uid = datasnapshot.getKey();
            }
            datosActualesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            ;

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Falló la lectura: " + error.getCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    ////PARA ACTUALIZAR DATOS DEL PERFIL Y FOTO
    profileIMG = root.findViewById(R.id.profile_img);
    addfotoperfil = root.findViewById(R.id.addphoto_img);
    nombreAp = root.findViewById(R.id.perfil_nombre);
    direccion = root.findViewById(R.id.perfil_direccion);
    telef = root.findViewById(R.id.perfil_telefono);


    actualizar = root.findViewById(R.id.perfil_btn);

    db.getReference().child("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    UserModel userModel = snapshot.getValue(UserModel.class);

                    Glide.with(getContext()).load(userModel.getFotoPerfil()).into(profileIMG);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });

    addfotoperfil.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intentIMG = new Intent();
            intentIMG.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intentIMG.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intentIMG, 33);
        }
    });


    actualizar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            updateUserProfile();
        }
    });
    return root;
}

private void updateUserProfile() {

    String newNombreAp = nombreAp.getText().toString();
    String newDireccion = direccion.getText().toString();
    String newTelef = telef.getText().toString();

    if (newNombreAp.equals("") && newDireccion.equals("") && newTelef.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Ingrese al menos un campo para actualizar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(user.getUid());
    usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            String currentNombreAp = snapshot.child("nombreAp").getValue(String.class);
            String currentDireccion = snapshot.child("direccion").getValue(String.class);
            String currentTelef = snapshot.child("telefono").getValue(String.class);

            if (!newNombreAp.equals("") && !newNombreAp.equals(currentNombreAp)) {
                usersRef.child("nombreAp").setValue(newNombreAp);
            }
            if (!newDireccion.equals("") && !newDireccion.equals(currentDireccion)) {
                usersRef.child("direccion").setValue(newDireccion);
            }
            if (!newTelef.equals("") && !newTelef.equals(currentTelef)) {
                usersRef.child("telefono").setValue(newTelef);
            }

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Dato/s actualizados correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            nombreAp.setText("");
            direccion.setText("");
            telef.setText("");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            // Manejar el error
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 33 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();

        //CORTAR IMAGEN
        UCrop uCrop = UCrop.of(imageUri, Uri.fromFile(new File(requireContext().getCacheDir(), "cropped_image.jpg")));

        // Configurar opciones de recorte
        uCrop.withAspectRatio(1, 1); // Proporción de aspecto 1:1
        uCrop.withMaxResultSize(2000, 2000); // Tamaño máximo del resultado
        uCrop.withOptions(getCropOptions()); // Opciones de recorte personalizadas

        uCrop.start(requireContext(), this);
    } else if (resultCode == UCrop.RESULT_ERROR) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error al recortar la imagen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (requestCode == UCrop.REQUEST_CROP && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Obtiene la imagen recortada
        final Uri croppedUri = UCrop.getOutput(data);

        // Aquí puedes actualizar la foto en Firebase Storage y obtener la URL de la imagen actualizada
        if (croppedUri != null) {
            final StorageReference reference = storage.getReference().child("fotoPerfil")
                    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid());
            reference.putFile(croppedUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "FOTO DE PERFIL ACTUALIZADA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    reference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            db.getReference().child("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())
                                    .child("fotoPerfil").setValue(uri.toString());

                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "FOTO DE PERFIL SUBIDA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            Glide.with(getContext()).load(croppedUri).into(profileIMG);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

private UCrop.Options getCropOptions() {
    UCrop.Options options = new UCrop.Options();
    options.setToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.purple_500));
    options.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.teal_200));
    options.setToolbarWidgetColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.purple_200)); // Establecer color de los widgets de la barra de herramientas
    options.setFreeStyleCropEnabled(false);
    options.setToolbarCropDrawable(R.drawable.ic_crop);
    options.setToolbarCancelDrawable(R.drawable.ic_cancel);
    options.setShowCropFrame(true);
    options.setShowCropGrid(true);
    options.setCompressionQuality(100); // Calidad de compresión de la imagen
    options.setHideBottomControls(true);
    options.setAllowedGestures(UCropActivity.ALL, UCropActivity.NONE, UCropActivity.ALL);
    options.setAspectRatioOptions(0, new AspectRatio("1:1", 1, 1));
    return options;
}
```

}

**Estos son los errores que muestra el Logcat:**

FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.elperlanegra, PID: 23770

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.elperlanegra/com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.ViewGroup.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)

at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)

at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)

at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.ViewGroup.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference

at com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity.processOptions(UCropActivity.java:297)

at com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity.setImageData(UCropActivity.java:209)

at com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity.onCreate(UCropActivity.java:141)

at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994)

at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)

at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)

at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)

at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)

at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

Answer (score 0):

En realidad el problema se encuentra en la Activity `UCropActivity`, esto lo indica el error mencionado en el `LogCat`:

> UCropActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke
> virtual method 'void android.view.ViewGroup.setVisibility(int)' on a
> null object reference

Esto indica que la vista a la cual deseas cambiar la visibilidad no existe en el layout que la `Activity` carga mediante `setContentView()`, o no estás obteniendo la referencia antes de llamar a `setContentView()`.